# Is there a 'simple' test one can perform to see if a function maps measurable sets to measurable sets?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know I'm probably missing a huge key point somewhere in my analysis background, but is there such a thing as a 'simple' test to check if a function does this? (Note: I am specifically considering Lebesgue measure.)

Comment: If it is absolutely continuous, then this is true. Not sure if this is a necessary condition though.

Comment: Are you sure? AFAIK, a.c takes sets of measure zero to sets of measure zero, but I don't know if measurable is sent to measurable. I would assume a homeomorphism may do the job.